# Anyone know what came of "Pyro?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

About 15-20 years ago there was an active project called Pyro. See for example:  https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/1047568.1047569 "In this article we describe a programming framework called Pyro, which provides a set of abstractions that allows students to write platform-independent robot programs." Pyro worked with ROS and maybe some other frameworks. I am trying to connect to that project, if anything is still happening there. Even if not, I'd like to take a look at whatever code is still left over. Does anyone know someone related to that project?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/353117/anyone-know-what-came-of-%22pyro?/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2020-05-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-24**:
I'll not close this for now -- due to the connection with ROS and the chance that there *may be * someone here who recognises the name, but I would really recommend you post this somewhere else.

A quick Google shows that at least one of the authors of the paper you link has a Github profile, so it should not be too difficult to get in touch with him.

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2020-05-24**:
Thanks. Indeed I've emailed people and have posted it elsewhere. I am casting a wide net :)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-24**:
For normal question this would be an reason to immediately close it, as cross-posting is not allowed.

Please edit your question and link to the other places you've posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From following up with the authors I believe that Pyro is no longer a supported project although the code may still be available.

---

Originally posted by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) with karma: 628 on 2020-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0